# Copy function with clipboard API

Tags: javascript, html

i need to copy to clipboard an input text (id=location) from an html form.
I am using this code:

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  
  if (navigator && navigator.clipboard && navigator.clipboard.writeText)
    return navigator.clipboard.writeText(str);
  return Promise.reject('The Clipboard API is not available.');
};
```

---

From this input:

```
    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Address"/>
    <button onclick="copyToClipboard('location')">Copy</button>
```

---

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You are writing the `str` parameter to the clipboard. And in `copyToClipboard('location')` you are passing `'location'` as the parameter, so "location" will be stored in the clipboard. If you want to copy the value in the input field, [you first need to get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript).

Comment: OK, i tried following the 3rd ethod. Now all i get is undefined..still trying/fighting

Comment: @Masinos Why the third method? Your `<input>` has an ID. Use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying to clipboard the world 'location' instead of the input value.

It is possible to access the content of the input using its Id:

```
document.getElementById("input_id").value;
```

In your case, to pass the value of the input:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard(document.getElementById('location').value)">Copy</button>
```